# Displaying like / unlike pages in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have been trying to make facebook page that will display different content depending on the Like / Unlike. I found the code below on this site which works to a certain extent however not in Chrome Browser - I also get a nasty pop-up that is XD Proxy. In firefox this pops up and then goes away before working perfectly. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Index.html (displayed in the iFrame)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />

    <title>BASE</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/example.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '114317821995273',
    status : true, 
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true  
  });
</script>


<div id="container_notlike">
YOU DONT LIKE
</div>

<div id="container_like">
YOU LIKE
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {

          var user_id = response.session.uid;
          var page_id = "187015391355550"; //Test Page
          var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
          var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

          the_query.wait(function(rows) {

              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                  $("#container_like").show();

                  //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

              } else {
                  $("#container_notlike").show();
                  //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
              }
          });


      } else {
        // user is not logged in
      }
    });

});
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can help. And thanks to the previous poster that has got me this far.

Comment: Is this on a third party site or on Facebook itself via a Page tab / Canvas (apps.facebook.com/foo)?

Comment: This might be too obvious but are you loading the Facebook API? I do not see that being pulled in anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your fql query needs a space after the page_id.
It should read:

```
var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+" and uid="+user_id;
```